# Unable to start receiver NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I have a BroadcastReceiver that receives an SMS and then is supposed to immediately send a reply SMS if the text has certain characters. Now it receives and sends the SMSs but it soon forces close giving something like: Unable to start receiver... NullPointerException... ActivityThread.handleReciever (paraphrasing) in the LogCat...what might be the issue? Here's my code, you're looking for the ELSE IF statement(that's the part that I'm currently testing):

```
public class Service extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (intent.getAction()
            .equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String msgFrom;
        if (bundle != null) {
            try {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                    String verificationCode = "717345221";
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    msgFrom = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    String encodeHash = Uri.encode("#");
                    msgFrom = "0" + msgFrom.substring(4) + encodeHash;
                    String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();

                    if (msgBody.startsWith(verificationCode)) {
                        this.abortBroadcast();
                        msgBody = msgBody.substring(verificationCode
                                .length());
                        try {
                            String dial = msgBody + "*" + msgFrom;
                            Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,
                                    Uri.parse("tel:" + dial));
                            call.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            context.startActivity(call);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.toString();
                        }
                    } else if (msgBody.contains("TEST123")) {
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "TEST123 text recieved",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        String transactionCode = null;
                        if (msgBody.length() > 9) {
                            transactionCode = msgBody.substring(0, 9);
                        }

                        String attachCode = "776f76wfuh";
                        String number = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                        String message = attachCode + transactionCode;

                        try {
                            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                                    context, 0, new Intent(context,
                                            Service.class), 0);
                            sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, pi,
                                    null);
                            Toast.makeText(context,
                                    "Text sent with attach code",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception
                            Log.d("Exception caught", e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception caught", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here's the LogCat:

```
10-31 20:42:05.269: E/AndroidRuntime(15080): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 20:42:05.269: E/AndroidRuntime(15080): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.adbionicpaymentsystem.Service: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-31 20:42:05.269: E/AndroidRuntime(15080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1805)
10-31 20:42:05.269: E/AndroidRuntime(15080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-31 20:42:05.269: E/AndroidRuntime(15080):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:981)
10-31 20:42:05.269: E/AndroidRuntime(15080):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-31 20:42:05.269: E/AndroidRuntime(15080):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-31 20:42:05.269: E/AndroidRuntime(15080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-31 20:42:05.269: E/AndroidRuntime(15080):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 20:42:05.269: E/AndroidRuntime(15080):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-31 20:42:05.269: E/AndroidRuntime(15080):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
10-31 20:42:05.269: E/AndroidRuntime(15080):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
10-31 20:42:05.269: E/AndroidRuntime(15080):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-31 20:42:05.269: E/AndroidRuntime(15080): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-31 20:42:05.269: E/AndroidRuntime(15080):    at com.adbionicpaymentsystem.Service.onReceive(Service.java:21)
10-31 20:42:05.269: E/AndroidRuntime(15080):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1794)
10-31 20:42:05.269: E/AndroidRuntime(15080):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Does `LogCat` provide call stack?

Comment: It was only the first if statement that can be considered irrelevant. Removed

Comment: @AdamArold - that's bad advice.  In this case we don't yet KNOW what is relevant to the problem - it's as likely to be in the code you caused the poster to remove as anywhere else.  With a null pointer exception, the majority of the task is to read the logcat and determine the relevant line of code.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yeah you have a point. Just reverted the changes.

Comment: Now you need to identify line 1805 - on which you have improperly used a null object, probably trying to call one if its methods.

Comment: Line 1805 isn't in any of my classes..it's in the system classes.

Comment: Sorry, you are right.  You didn't post enough of the logcat.  There will be more, including a reference to a line of your code.

Comment: And line 21 is?  We can't figure it out from the posted excerpt, as there are going to be import statements at the top of the file...

Comment: .equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) that's line 21

Comment: apparently `intent.getAction()` is null

Comment: You can check for that at least, and if you are curious log the fact that it has occurred.

Comment: What can I use instead of intent.getAction() ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was I had another service running on the test device that seemingly interferes with this service

Answer (score 0):

be sure to have the permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

and note that **sendTextMessage**

```
This method was deprecated in API level 4.
Use android.telephony.SmsManager.
```

Comment: Poster indicates that it works initially, so this is not the problem.